# Настройка команды терминала для выполнения CodeBox в CherryTree

Tags: ide, настройка

Система Linux Mint 21.1 Vera Cinnamon 5.6.7. Ядро 5.15.0-60-generic. Python 3.
В программе CherryTree есть функция вставки и выполнения кода CodeBox.
Вставляю как CodeBox и выполняю простейший код:

```
a = 2  
b = 3  
c = a + b  
print (c)
```

Но не появляется окно терминала с результатом выполнения кода.
В подразделе настроек "Обычный текст и код" стоит команда терминала по умолчанию xterm -hold -geometry 180x45 -e "" &  и python3 <tmp_src_path>
Пробовал подбирать по аналогии настройки  из Geany.
С командой x-terminal-emulator "< command >" при выполнении кода появляется окно терминала, но без результата выполнения.
Подскажите, какие ввести настройки, чтобы отображался результат выполнения кода?

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, нужно установить актуальную версию (сейчас 0.99.54).
В ней код выполняется и отображается результат во встроенном терминале с настройками по умолчанию.
Команды для установки:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:giuspen/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo install cherrytree
```